# milliseconds Delay/Lag when Switching Tabs in BottomNavigationView in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

### Question

I'm currently working on an Android app where I'm using a 'BottomNavigationView' to switch between tabs in my application. However, I've noticed that there is a noticeable delay or lag when switching between these tabs, impacting the user experience.

#### Problem Details

- I'm using the standard `BottomNavigationView` component.
- Each tab in the `BottomNavigationView` is associated with a different fragment.
- The lag occurs when tapping on different tabs, and it takes a milliseconds before the new fragment becomes visible.

#### What I've Tried

1. Checked for any heavy operations or computations in my fragment's `onCreateView` or `onResume` methods.
2. Verified that I'm not loading large images or data on the UI thread.
3. Ensured that my fragments are not performing network operations on the main thread.

#### Code Samples

Here's a simplified version of my `MainActivity` with the `BottomNavigationView` setup:

```
// MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.tab1:
                    // Load Fragment 1
                replaceFragment(new Fragment1());
                    break;
                case R.id.tab2:
                    // Load Fragment 2
                replaceFragment(new Fragment2());
                    break;
                case R.id.tab3:
                    // Load Fragment 3
                replaceFragment(new Fragment3());
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

- What could be causing this delay or lag when switching tabs in my BottomNavigationView?
- Are there any specific best practices or optimizations I should consider for improving tab switching performance?
- How can I diagnose and resolve this issue effectively?

Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!